# Why is jaxws-maven-plugin showing these warnings?

Tags: maven, jaxb, jax-ws, wsimport, jaxws-maven-plugin

Everything is working fine, but I am puzzled as to what's going on with these warnings.

When I run the `wsimport` goal, for each of my project's test dependencies it reports that it "cannot find file".

```
[INFO] --- jaxws-maven-plugin:2.3:wsimport (default-cli) @ my-project ---
[WARNING] cannot find file for com.realvnc.services:test-utils
[WARNING] cannot find file for org.cassandraunit:cassandra-unit
[WARNING] cannot find file for org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-test
[WARNING] cannot find file for com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Questions**:

- What exactly is this file and what is looking for it?
- Is this symptomatic of some problem I haven't noticed yet?
- Is there a way to remove these warnings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are experiencing an already reported [bug](https://github.com/mojohaus/jaxws-maven-plugin/issues/15):

> WsImportMojo: warning "cannot find file for" for test artefacts

The issue is still open (at the time of writing) and fix would be probably availabled with version `2.5.2-SNAPSHOT` (no yet released and hence not available on Maven Central).

Hence, concerning your questions:

> What exactly is this file and what is looking for it?

The warning is issued in [this line](https://github.com/mojohaus/jaxws-maven-plugin/blob/971c5a7f0f167112b65cde416a409a3a0f94c204/src/main/java/org/codehaus/mojo/jaxws/WsImportMojo.java#L587) while scanning for artifacts (dependencies) but not filtering by scope (`test` and `provided` should indeed be ignored) or optional dependencies.

> Is this symptomatic of some problem I haven't noticed yet?

No, you can ignore it. It will be gone in future versions.

> Is there a way to remove these warnings?

No, for the moment. Again, they will be gone in a future version.